# does census data has to follow a normal law before doing a mean comparison by an ANOVA?

Tags: anova, normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics, census

I'm working on some socio demographical (Age, tenure, salary, etc...) data to predict absenteism. I have all the employee data, so i have the entire population.

When i run a descriptive analysis for my age variable per absence category, here is what i have :

abs age mean
(0) 35,41259805
(1) 35,14586814
(2) 35,77493261

So i was thinking about running an anova to be sure that this difference is actually significative or not (witch seem to be the case here)

But i was told that this can be done only when the data follow a normal law. Does this also apply for census data ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the only difference between census and sampled data is that we need to infer the population distribution from the sample, but with census data we can be certain of what the distribution is. If the distribution is not normal then the ANOVA will not give accurate results.